# Разные header на главной странице и всем сайте

Tags: opencart

**Opencart 3.0**. Нужно сделать различными шапку страницы на главной и всего сайта. Много просматривал материалы, на **opencart 3.0** нашел решение, но до конца не понял.

> Make two files, header.twig and home_header.twig
>
> In catalog/controller/common/header.php there is a function index(),
>   this uses header.twig
>
> Write another method for example index_home() in header.php and copy
>   the index() body in this function (make any changes if needed)
>
> In index_home() change
>
> **return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);** to
>
> **return $this->load->view('common/home_header', $data);** If you check
>   functions of every controller there is a line
>
> **$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');** this will
>   call header.twig Whichever function you need to use home_header.twig
>   you can replace
>
> **$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');** in that
>   function with
>
> **$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header/index_home');**
>   This will use home_header.twig

---

Не понимаю эту строчку:

> Write another method for example index_home() in header.php and copy
>   the index() body in this function (make any changes if needed)
>   непонятно мне "copy the index() body in this function"

Объясните, как возможно решить эту проблему.
Функцию я взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965523/how-to-show-another-header-template-at-home-page)

Answer (score 0):

Все достаточно просто. Добавьте в метод `controller/common/header::index` входящие параметры, например `$args` и в контроллере вывода главной страницы просто сообщайте хедеру, что это главная страница:

```
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // какой-то код

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header', ['is_home' => true]); // передаем в контроллер хедера информацию, что эта страница - главная
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/home', $data));
    }
}
```

Не забудьте добавить саму проверку и соответствующий вывод в контроллере хедера в зависимости от переданных аргументов:

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index(array $args=[]) {
        // если есть аргумент is_home - устанавливаем его булевое значение, если нет берем значение по умолчанию false
        $is_home = isset($args['is_home']) ? (bool) $args['is_home'] : false; 

        // Какой-то код

        // Если домашняя - то 1 метод формирования хедера, есть нет, то другой
        return $is_home ? $this->homeHeader() : $this->commonHeader();
    }

    private function homeHeader() {
        // какой-то код
        return $this->load->view("common/header_home", $data);
    }

    private function commonHeader() {
        // какой-то код
        return $this->load->view("common/header", $data);
    }
}
```

Таким образом,Ваша главная страница будет иметь другой header, а все остальные - основной

Comment: Дорогой Peresada, конечно спасибо. Но я не так силен в программировании. Если есть возможность внеси коррективы в файл header.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаёте новый файл из `common/header.twig`, например `common/home-header.twig`, кастомизируете под нужды;
2. Создаёте под него контроллер-клон `common/header.php`, например `common/home-header.php`, кастомизируете функционал по необходимости;
3. В контроллере `home.php` переопределяете контроллер хедера:

   ```
   $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
   // заменяете на: 
   $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/home-header');
   ```

Comment: Привет Кирилл. Спасибо что ответил. Но этот вариант не срабатывает. Также выходят одинаковый header, хотя в одном изи них были изменения.

Comment: @marcoss кеш твига чистил, когда вносил новые файлы и исправления?

Answer (score 0):

Write another method for example index_home() in header.php and copy the index() body in this function (make any changes if needed) непонятно мне "copy the index() body in this function"

Здесь же все достаточно просто! Перевод: Напишите еще один метод(функцию), например index_home() в header.php и скопируйте туда содержимое функции index() (сделайте какие-либо изменения если необходимо).

То есть дублируете функцию index() со всем ее содержимым (копировать, вставить) и переименовываете ее в index_home(). Чистите кэш и все работает! У меня по-крайней мере точно работает 3,0,2,0